# Please help how to get rid of dust mites which causes itching at night

Tags: dust, sleeping, health

Whenever I go to sleep at night,itchiness starts to me,which causes red rashes.and no sleep also.
Any one please suggest how to get rid of this soon.

Comment: What have you already tried? For example, a bedding/mattress vacuum cleaner? And have you had allergy tests done? Could be what you wash the sheets with or even the shower gel you are using before bed.

Comment: Take a torch to bed with you; when the itching starts, throw back the covers and turn the torch on and have a close look - dust mites are not the major cause of itching at night, the two primary insect causes are fleas followed by bedbugs, although the latter usually just cause bite marks with itching next day, but its not impossible they cause itching immediately. If you see black specks and they jump, they're fleas. Alternatively, you may be sensitive to laundry products

Comment: you might also research scabies - the rash, and itchiness, worse at night, are typical symptoms.

Comment: Are you sure it's insects? Did you change your brand of shower gel or soap or washing detergent lately? You might have dry skin, that can itch too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it *is* caused by dust mites, then

- First clean the bedroom, flooring, furniture and bedding **thoroughly**,
- clean any air ducts and change air filters, *then*
- use [zippered mattress protector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LI7HG6A) and [pillow covers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BM8KC3E).

First, though, check with an allergist who could test for specific allergens, because this itching might be caused by laundry softener, detergent or the fabric itself. Such a doctor might also prescribe a course of treatment, such as desensitization ("allergy shots"), medication, or perhaps just an ointment for dry skin.

Comment: If you have a roommate who thinks it's funny to "prank" people, he/she might have sprinkled itching powder in your bed. (Yes, you can buy "itching powder" online.)

Answer (score 1):

My family had this problem with a different kind of mite that came from chickens. We had to put this anti mite stuff in the chicken pen and then we had to shampoo the carpet of the whole house and give everything a good clean off.